# Define POJO for changing JSON responses

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson2

I am using Java 8/Spring 5 to call a third-party API.   I am using HttpClient which works well, and I have a POJO that works 99% of the time.

When I call this one service, the JSON looks like:

```
{"field1":"a",
 "field2":"b",
 "field3:"c"}
```

Based on different parameters it could come back as:

```
{"field1":"a",
 "field2":{
    "subfield1:"x",
    "subfield2:"y",
    "subfield3":"z"},
 "field3:"c"}
```

I am using the latest FastJacksonMapper to convert from JSON string to a Java POJO, and it works in the first instance, but not in the second instance.

I know it may be common for JSON to change based on requests, but I expect JSON to be a little more consistent.

Any thoughts on how I could tweak my POJO?  Any JSON annotations I can use to fix this?  Or, maybe create a separate POJO so that in case one fails, the other picks up?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting a primitive value or an object as part of `field2` ? if you are expecting both (based on parameters), then it's a bad design for your API and the clients consuming it.  This will create plenty of headaches (now and in the future). Proceed at your own peril.

Comment: It's not my API ... I definitely wouldn't do that.   This is an API from a third-party, another company altogether.   I agree, this design is a problem.   The best part is, this company is next door to us, and I would walk over and talk to the CEO.   :-D     They are really a bunch of nice guys!

Comment: I see... question: is it consistently returning a value with a given parameter set and an object with a different parameter set? - If the response received is consistent given the parameters submitted, then you could at least have two separate methods (with different mappers) and use one or the other depending on which parameters you send.  In other words, since you know which type of question you are asking, you could then tailor the handling of the answer based on it

Answer (score 0):

So for the same URL and http method you can get different payloads? The same key "field2" might have a string value in option A and a different object in option B? IMHO that's bad design of API.

That third-party API having any description like swagger? Such description will help you generate correct POJO with proper annotations.

If such documentation is not available try to use generators like: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Either<Type1Obj, Type2Obj> getPojoFromJson(String json) {
        try {
            // Type1Obj from json
            return Either.left(obj1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                //Type2Obj from json
                return Either.right(obj2);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                //fallback
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: Adding some commentary about what it is that you are trying to do with the given code goes a long way.  A bunch of code without explanations helps no one.

Comment: Here I was trying to convert the json data to Type1 pojo if exception then i am trying to convert it typ2 pojo and setting the return type in Either based on successful conversion.